# Yii Modules in Craft, samples?

Tags: yii, modules

Does anybody know of a collection or library of Yii Modules online?

I'm trying to understand how easy they can be moved from one application to another, are we going to see something similar to the plugin store for modules within Craft? :O

Comment: Plugins are classes that extend the module classes so they can be installed or uninstalled. Besides that plugins are exactly the same like modules. We won't see a module store since modules are nothing special in Craft. You can use every existing yii2 module in your Craft project as well. Maybe you could explain in detail what you would like to know? Otherwise I would suggest you to read Yii2 resources for modules https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of Craft CMS, Modules typically would be used for adding functionality to the website itself. As such, you'd use it for things that are specific to that project. Check out the article [Enhancing a Craft CMS 3 Website with a Custom Module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module) for details.

You can also generate your module scaffolding via [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and articles Andrew and Robert. The similarity of the two were causing the confusion.